# Adding a filter to specific product pages which are unique - using Google Tag Manager & Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I have coded a new product page design for products that only have a single size and single color. I would like to have a way to only see those pages in GA to get a sense of success once published.

Comment: I don't want to split the traffic. I just want add a dimension or content group something so I can see all the URLs which has been effected in GA. Sorry maybe I need to update my question.

Comment: Ok so you probably need to set up a second analytics property and have GTM work with multiple properties: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/send-google-analytics-tag-multiple-properties/ . Another way is to set up custom events that trigger only on your specified pages and monitor that in the same analytics property: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/simple-custom-event-listeners-gtm/

Comment: Another analytics property? Are you crazy?

Comment: Please also update your answer, it is not clear what information you want.

Comment: I am guessing a custom dimension can be passed if that product page contains something like a unique ID to the body tag.

Comment: Yes, custom dimensions could be used for this. Is this the answer to your question, or do you have any further questions in connection to the realisation of this in GTM?